# Dynamically create Cipher using configuration: What parameters are necessary?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptoapi

Java uses the `Cipher` class as an abstraction to the specific cipher implementations. In my project, I mainly use symmetric block ciphers (AES, Twofish, 3DES, ...) and I'm looking for a way to dynamically create/initialize any possible symmetric block ciphers (using an XML configuration), because I'd like to make encryption configurable.

*Example:* `<transformer type="cipher" cipher="AES/GCM/NoPadding" keysize="256" iv="true" unlimitedstrength="true" />`

will be translated to:

```
// Create secretKey using 'keysize' ...

if (encryption.isUnlimitedCrypto()) {
    Encryption.enableUnlimitedCrypto();
}

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryption.getCipherStr(), Encryption.PROVIDER);

if (encryption.isIvNeeded()) {
    byte[] iv = ... 
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
}
else {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
}
```

My question ist: **What parameters are necessary to instantiate any symmetric block cipher in Java?**

*Parameters (already identified):*

- Cipher String: String for Cipher.getInstance(..), e.g. AES/CBC/PKCSPadding
- Key size: Size of the key for the key generation (or the PBE key derivation function)
- IV needed: Indicates whether an IV is needed, e.g. "true" for CBC and GCM mode, but not for ECB
- IV size: Indicates the size of the IV (right now I assume IV size = key size, correct?)
- Unlimited strength needed: Indicates whether enabling the unlimited strength policy files is necessary
- *Others?*

*Original source/project:*

- Implementation: https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany/blob/e3d11300b34c133d01431d6e041b4eb39b6bec33/src/org/syncany/chunk/CipherTransformer.java
- Desired Usage in Tests: https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany/blob/e3d11300b34c133d01431d6e041b4eb39b6bec33/tests/org/syncany/tests/config/EncryptionTest.java#L114

Comment: IV size = key size? No! IV size = block size, unless the instructions for the mode state otherwise

Answer (score 2):

All modes other than `ECB` require an IV. The IV will always be equal to the block size of the cipher (16 bytes for AES, 8 bytes for 3DES). `ECB` mode is insecure when encrypting more than 1 block of plaintext with the same key, and should not be allowed if you want confidentiality to be ensured.

The algorithm used will dictate what key size is required. AES, for example, requires 128, 192, or 256 Unlimited strength policies need to be installed for 192 and 256 if using Java's standard crypto API. The unlimited strength policy is not something you can toggle with code, it has to be installed in the end users JRE.

If you care about securing data in transit (and this project has real security needs), I can not urge you strongly enough to use SSL/TLS for this instead. Creating a secure crypto system is difficult to do, and bulk encryption (i.e. symmetric ciphers like AES, 3DES) are not enough by themselves to ensure security. You also need a cryptographically strong source of random data, a safe key exchange process and integrity verification. Confidentially is difficult to provide without also ensuring integrity which is generally provided by using MAC functions. There are all pitfalls to avoid when implementing a secure crypto system like making sure you use different keys for cipher and MAC, verifying MACs correctly so as not to create a timing attack vector, using a proper random generator, ensuring integrity so as not to create a padding oracle, etc.

As you can see there are a lot of moving parts to protecting transmitted data, and doing it from scratch can lead to vulnerabilities introduced by incorrectly chosen or misconfigured crypto primitives. This is why TLS is often recommended.

Below is an example of an anonymous (no authentication) TLS session established by two sockets. This example is not secure because neither of the parties authenticates the other, however confidentiality and integrity are established. The reason I'm using this insecure cipher suite in the example is it is easy to demonstrate TLS usage without getting in to keystores and truststores (used for the authentication part)

The cipher suite being used is `TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`, which is not normally enabled by default, because of the aforementioned lack of authentication. Below I break down this cipher suite

- TLS - This cipher suite was introduced by the TLS standard.
- ECDH_anon - Eliptic Cuve Diffie-Hellman algorithm is used for key agreement, however the key agreement is not authenticated.
- AES_128_CBC - Advanced Encryption Standard with a 128-bit key length in Cipher Block Chaining mode is used for bulk encryption.
- SHA - Secure Hash Algorithm is used to ensure integrity of the encrypted data.

Example follows.

```
package com.stackoverflow._19505091;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

public class AnonTLSExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        /* No certs for this example so we are using ECDH_anon exchange. */
        String[] cipherSuites = {"TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"};
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

        /* No certificates, use default secure random source.
         * If we were using authentication (and you should in a real
         * system), this is where we would load 
         * keystores and truststores. */
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);

        /* Create server socket. */
        SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket) sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(12345);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

        /*
         * Normally when authentication is used only the client authenticates
         * the server. If you want the server to also authenticate the client
         * set this to true. This will establish bidirectional trust in the session.
         */
        ss.setWantClientAuth(false);

        /* Start server thread. */
        new Thread(new Server(ss), "ServerThread").start();

        /* Create client socket. */
        SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        s.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

        /* Connect to server. */
        System.out.println("Client: Connecting...");
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 12345));
        System.out.println("Client: Connected");

        /* Print out some TLS info for this connection. */
        SSLSession session = s.getSession();
        System.out.println("Client: Session secured with P: " + session.getProtocol() + " CS: " + session.getCipherSuite());

        /* Send the secret message. */
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String message = "Secret Message.";
        System.out.println("Client: Sending: " + message);
        dos.writeUTF(message);

        /* Wait for server to close stream. */
        System.out.println("Client: Waiting for server to close...");
        s.getInputStream().read();

        /* Close client socket. */
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Client: Done.");
    }


}

class Server implements Runnable {

    private final ServerSocket ss;

    public Server(ServerSocket ss){
        this.ss = ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
         /* Wait for client to connect. */
         System.out.println("Server: Waiting for connection...");
         Socket s = ss.accept();
         System.out.println("Server: Connected.");

         /* Read secret message. */
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
         String message = dis.readUTF();
         System.out.println("Server: Received Message: " + message);

         /* Close our sockets. */
         s.close();
         ss.close();
         System.out.println("Server: Done.");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information about the IV (IV size = block size), and ECB being the only mode without IV. My application has no influence on the transport security, so SSL/TLS is not of my concern. Unlimited strength can be programatically enabled using reflection: https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany/blob/e3d11300b34c133d01431d6e041b4eb39b6bec33/src/org/syncany/config/Encryption.java#L71

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not fully answer my question. I still don't know if the given parameters fully identify a cipher (in order to programatically create it)

Comment: Solved it: Implementation here: https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany/blob/dcccd0df1e860852bf7d104ecd562ff5c0a0800f/src/org/syncany/crypto/CipherSpec.java and usage here: https://github.com/binwiederhier/syncany/blob/dcccd0df1e860852bf7d104ecd562ff5c0a0800f/src/org/syncany/crypto/CipherUtil.java#L114